# how to delete rows with only zeros from matlab table?

Tags: matlab

```
T = table([1;4;0],[0;5;0],[3;6;0])
```

How can I delete rows that contain only zeros? `rmmissing` doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `table` brace indexing, together with `any`. Like this:

```
>> T(any(T{:,:}, 2), :)

ans =

  2x3 table

    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____

     1       0       3  
     4       5       6
```

Breaking this down - the expression `T{:,:}` results in a numeric matrix formed from the elements of the `table`. Calling `any(..., 2)` results in a `logical` column vector which is `true` if any of the elements of the corresponding row are non-zero. Finally, this is combined with standard `table` `()` indexing to select only the rows that have a non-zero element.